# Active Directory: get the roles of a user

Tags: active-directory, ldap, roles

1)- I'm looking for the LDAP's query (Active Directory) to get roles (groups) of a given user without specifying the dinstinguished name of the user.

I'm able to get this using this request: (&(objectclass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=admin,ou=users,ou=OUTest,dc=example,dc=com))

but i don't want to specify the whole root to the user (ou=users,ou=OUTest,dc=example,dc=com).

2)- How i get the groups of a given user using "sAMAccountName" instead of Common name CN?

(*) member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941 is used to get all nested groups in Active Directory.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation about the [`1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941` matching rule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx) in ActiveDirectory is unambiguous. Emphasis mine:

> `1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941`
>   `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN`
>
> **This rule is limited to filters that apply to the DN.** This is a special "extended" match operator that walks the chain of ancestry in objects all the way to the root until it finds a match.

It is not possible to use it with anything but a full DN because it matches against attributes that contain full DNs.

> but i don't want to specify the whole root to the user

Though luck. ;)

Build your program in a way that lets the user work with something more convenient, for example `samAccountName` and translates this into a search string that has the full DN.

---

For example in Powershell:

```
function Get-ADUserGroups($username) {
    if ($username) {
        Get-ADUser $username | ForEach-Object {
            $userDN = $_.DistinguishedName
            $ldapFilter = "(&(objectClass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=$userDN))"

            Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter $ldapFilter
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
Get-ADUserGroups userXYZ
```

---

Or, for the sake of it, the same thing in regular Windows batch (GetADUserGroups.bat):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set USER=%~1

if "%USER%" neq "" (
    for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dsquery user -samid "%USER%"') do (
        set "LDAP_FILTER=(&(objectClass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=%%~d))"
        dsquery * -filter "!LDAP_FILTER!" -limit 1000
    )
)
```

Usage

```
GetADUserGroups userXYZ
```